# Why is this code not returning a list of phone numbers using the re module's compile and search function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn how to use the compile and search functions in the `re` module and I was pretty sure this code was right. I am trying to return the 3 phone numbers in the string as a print output but it keeps returning `none` instead.

In earlier iterations of similar code I was using `print(mo.group())` instead of `print(mo)` as it appears in this updated code and it was returning the numbers no problem. I tried using `print(mo.group())` with this code but that threw an `AttributeError` where the

> 'NoneType' object has no attributable 'group.'

What am I doing wrong?

I am certain it is a stupid and obvious mistake but I just cannot find it... Here's my code:

```
import re
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'((\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d(,)?){3}') 
mo = phoneRegex.search('My numbers are 415-555-1234, 555-4242, 212-555-0000.')
print(mo)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You've enclosed the entire expression `(\d\d\d-)?\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d(,)?` in a capturing group that must be repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [6]: import re
   ...:
   ...: phoneRegex = re.compile(r"((\d{3}-)?\d{3}-\d{4}([,.] )?){3}")
   ...:
   ...: mo = phoneRegex.search('My numbers are 415-555-1234, 555-4242, 212-555-0
   ...: 000.')
   ...:
   ...: print(mo.group())

415-555-1234, 555-4242, 212-555-0000
```

To capture individual number:

```
In [20]: phoneRegex2 = re.compile(r"((\d{3}-)?\d{3}-\d{4})")

In [21]: for i in phoneRegex2.findall('My numbers are 415-555-1234, 555-4242, 212-555-0000.'):
...:     print(i[0])
...:
415-555-1234
555-4242
212-555-0000
```

Comment: So I updated the code as per your suggestion and I get this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "16RepetitionInRegexPatterns.py", line 58, in <module>
    print(mo.group())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: On my terminal it's working fine. Make sure you are using the regex pattern exactly. Though I would suggest capture each number as a separate group, that would be more error proof. I'll add a section for that part

Comment: Thanks. I still have no idea what is wrong. Functionally, my original code was written the exact same as your first suggestion. After spending around an hour trying to figure out my mistake I was not able to see any differences that would have caused the AttributeError I mentioned above.

Comment: In your first code, you need to add a space character after the comma because you have a space after the comma separated numbers.